# Causes of Misophonia

Tags: neuroscience, brain, hearing

Whether it's snacking on chips, munching on salad, or simply chewing gum, when I hear someone do it within an earshot, it drives me completely bonkers!

It doesn't matter if it's my girlfriend, my mom, someone sitting next to me at the office, or random stranger on the train, it bothers me just as much. The "mouth open" chewing type makes me want to get violent, and I often find myself in a blind rage. I also notice the slower, and more "deliberate" the chewing/munching is, the more I get tense and more it bothers me.

Sometimes I feel like they are doing it on purpose, and completely fake, sort of like a commercial where they exaggerate the act of eating.

I want to know more about [Misophonia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misophonia) or "Hatred of Sound"?

Answer (score 5):

### Misophonia

> Misophonia is a relatively unexplored chronic condition in which a
> person experiences autonomic arousal (analogous to an involuntary
> “fight-or-flight” response) to certain innocuous or repetitive sounds
> such as chewing, pen clicking, and lip smacking. Misophonics report
> anxiety, panic, and rage when exposed to trigger sounds, compromising
> their ability to complete everyday tasks and engage in healthy and
> normal social interactions.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbjWT.jpg)

### Physiology

**The auditory pathways may be functioning normally, but there is an abnormally strong reaction of the limbic (emotional system) and autonomic nervous system (body control system) to which the auditory system is intimately connected.**

Several definitions are listed for the disorder, including:

1. “Abnormally strong negative reactions of the autonomic and limbic systems to specific sounds resulting from enhanced functional connections between the auditory and limbic systems for these sounds.  The auditory system works in a normal manner, without abnormally high activation.  At the behavioral level, sounds specific for a given patient evoke strong negative reactions.  This situation may cause general negative attitude to sound as well.  When fear is dominant emotion (patient is afraid of sound) phonophobia occurs (phobia – fear).  Phonophobia is a specific case of misophonia.”
2. “Selective sound sensitivity should be considered a type of misophonia, where soft sounds (typically eating and breathing sounds made by emotional attachment figures) are the focus, and the quality of those sounds causes annoyance and rage in the listener.”
3. “Pre-puberty seems to be a very common age of onset for the majority of those with misophonia, with lifetime persistence for most cases, and there appears to be a genetic component.”
4. “Misophonia can be considered abnormally strong connections between the autonomic and limbic resulting from enhanced connections between the auditory and limbic systems.  These connections encompass both a high level of cortical level loop with involvement with cognition as well as subconscious connections, most probably involving the link between the medial geniculate body and the amygdale. The functions of these connections are governed by the principles of conditioned reflexes.”

[image]
<sub>(source: [wordpress.com](https://lifewithmisophonia.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/limbic.gif))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [wordpress.com](https://lifewithmisophonia.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/ear-anatomy.jpg))</sub>

[image]

### source:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbjWT.jpg) [Misophonia: physiological investigations and case descriptions](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3691507/)
[2] [MISOPHONIA 4S Provider Network USA](http://www.misophonia-provider.com/What_is_Misophonia_4S_.html)

Great Site: http://lifewithmisophonia.wordpress.com/